# Is there any other way to absolutely position paragraph/phrase in ITEXT without using writer object and column text class

Tags: java, templates, itext, positioning, invoice

This is that I am using and want to position the **Powered by** at the bottom of the page I needed without using the writer object [image: i want the powered by to be displayed at the bottom of the pdf]

```
package pdf_invoice;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Article {
    
    public static final String RESULT
        = "E:\\InvoiceEdit.pdf";
   
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, DocumentException 
    {
        new Article().createPdf(RESULT);
    }
    public void createPdf(String filename) throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        
        PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(filename));
        
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("This is a new paragraph"));
        document.add(new Paragraph("This is a new paragraph"));
        document.add(new Paragraph("This is a new paragraph"));
        
        PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setTotalWidth(595f);
     
        PdfPCell cell=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Powered by"));
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        cell.setBorderWidth(0f);
        table.addCell(cell);
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        
        System.out.println("generated");

    }
}
```

I dont find any other way than creating table and positioning than using the `ColumnText` and using writer object.

Comment: Itext before version 7 did not offer text positioning when adding it via the `Document` class. You could only position it via `PdfWriter` methods. (Ok, probably doing some complicated and brittle table layout you could approximately do some positioning, too, but this would be more complicated and brittle than the `PdfWriter` methods. )

Comment: by the way, if you want that **Powered by** on each page, you may want to use page events...